# Error when using Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

I use Eclipse long time ago, it's great for me. But today, Eclipse is error when I try to close Eclipse:

> Problems occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench.
>     Problems occurred during save.
>     org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl.getXmlStandalone()Z

Now, I can't create new Java Project, I click on it, but nothing happen. 
Anybody can help me ?

P.s: I have just installed pae kernel for Ubuntu 32 bit 5 days ago. Should I install Ubuntu 64 bit for programming ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know even the latest Ubuntu comes with GCJ which still seems to have trouble with running eclipse (check it by running *java --version* in a terminal). Uninstalling **gcj** and installing **sun-java6-jdk** should solve the problem.